# DisclosureGroup is not expandable while using ForEach and trying to unwrap data in it

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to add an expander/Disclosure to my data, however, once I try to use "if let data = category_values[shortcuts]" to unwrap the value, the DisclosureGroup will be not able to expand and show label only.

```swift
struct Demo: View {
    @ObservedObject var configSocket: ConfigSocket
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {

                if let rebindData = configSocket.configData["Rebind"] as? [String: [String: [String: Any?]]] {
                    ForEach(Array(rebindData.keys.sorted { $0 < $1 }), id: \.self) { category in
                        if let category_values = rebindData[category]{
                            if let cate_data = Array(category_values.keys.sorted { $0 < $1 }) as?[String]{
                                DisclosureGroup {
                                    ForEach(cate_data, id: \.self) { shortcuts in
                                        Text(shortcuts)
                                        if let data = category_values[shortcuts]{ //if comment this if let part, 
                                            let _ = print(shortcuts)             // The DisclosureGroup will be expandable and show Text above,
                                        }                                        //but if keep this part, it won't works
                                    }
                                } label: {
                                    Text(category)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```